# Binomial coefficients based question

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$\binom {m}{0}+\binom {m}{1}-\binom {m}{2}-\binom {m}{3}+\binom {m}{4}+\binom {m}{5}-\binom {m}{6}-\binom {m}{7}+........=0$ if and only if for some positive integer k,then $m=$

$(A)4k\hspace{1cm} (B)4k+1\hspace{1cm}(C)4k+2\hspace{1cm}(D)4k+3$

My try:$\binom {m}{0}+\binom {m}{1}+\binom {m}{4}+\binom {m}{5}+....=\binom {m}{2}+\binom {m}{3}+\binom {m}{6}+\binom {m}{7}+.....$

But i could not judge the value of $m$.Any hints or guidance is required.

Comment: if and only if ***what*** for some positive integer $k$?

Comment: You might note that $\binom {m}{0}+\binom {m}{1}-\binom {m}{2}-\binom {m}{3}+\binom {m}{4}+\binom {m}{5}-\binom {m}{6}-\binom {m}{7}+\cdots \binom {m}{m}=2-(1-1)^m$

Comment: Have you at least tested this with $m=0,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$ to see how the land lies? Include such attempts. Otherwise you give the impression that you want your homework outsourced.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,No sir,i dont want to outsource my homework.I never thought that way by putting particular values.

Comment: Sorry about sounding a bit harsh at first. I have just seen a few too many questions of this type. My generic answer is admittedly  overkill for the purposes of this question. The general advice of testing it for small values of the parameter (when it can be done with minimum effort as is the case here) has been a battle cry in science since the days of Galilei who refuted Aristotle by carrying out experiments with falling objects of varying weights :-) (May be even earlier - particularly outside the narrow scope of Europe - but I've seen it attributed to Galilei)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This falls into the following class of problems.

> Evaluate $$S=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k\binom n k,$$ where the coefficients $c_k$ form a sequence that repeats periodically. That is, there exists an integer $m>0$ such that
>    $c_{k+m}=c_k$ for all relevant $k$.

These can be handled as follows. Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/m}$. Then, by the binomial theorem, we have for all integers $\ell, 0\le\ell<m,$ the result
$$
S(\ell)=\sum_{k=0}^n \zeta^{\ell k}\binom n k=(1+\zeta^\ell)^n.
$$
Because $\zeta^{\ell(k+m)}=\zeta^{\ell k}\cdot\zeta^{m\ell}=\zeta^{\ell k},$ the sum $S(\ell)$ is of the above type. Furthermore, all the sums of this type are linear combinations of the sums $S(\ell)$. This is immediate from discrete Fourier analysis, but you can also see it as follows. The sequence of coefficients is fully determined, if we know $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{m-1}$. So if we can find coefficients $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{m-1}$ such that the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{cases}
1\cdot x_0+1\cdot x_1+1\cdot x_2+\cdots+1\cdot x_{m-1}=c_0,&\\
1\cdot x_0+\zeta\cdot x_1+\zeta^2\cdot x_2+\cdots+\zeta^{m-1}\cdot x_{m-1}=c_1,\\
\vdots\\
1\cdot x_0+\zeta^j\cdot x_1+\zeta^{2j}\cdot x_2+\cdots+\zeta^{(m-1)j}\cdot x_{m-1}=c_j,\\
\vdots\\
1\cdot x_0+\zeta^{m-1}\cdot x_1+\zeta^{2(m-1)}\cdot x_2+\cdots+\zeta^{(m-1)^2}\cdot x_{m-1}=c_{m-1}
\end{cases}
$$
holds, then
$$
S=x_0 S(0)+x_1 S(1)+\cdots+x_{m-1}S(m-1).
$$
You see that the determinant of the coefficient matrix of this system is of the Vandermonde type, so the system has a unique solution. Alternatively, you can do an inverse Fourier transform, and figure out that
$$
x_\ell=\frac1m\sum_{j=0}^m\zeta^{-j\ell}c_j
$$
is a solution.

In your case $m=4$, $c_0=c_1=1,$ $c_2=c_3=-1$ and $\zeta=i$. Leaving the rest to you.

Answer (score 5):

The question is multiple-choice: to answer efficiently (and quickly) such questions when you are stuck proving the statement from scratch (or don't have time), *you just have to eliminate 3 options to find the right (remaining) one*. That is, find a counterexample for 3 out of 4 options, the simplest being by trying the simplest solution: here, for $k=1$.

Answer (score 3):

The number $m $ should be odd.

because we should to show that $ \binom {m}{n}  $  & $\binom {m}{m-n} $ should be be simplify with each other.

then $D$ is correct.

you can use induction that every number like $4k+3$ right for this equation.