# How do I prove ${\binom{n}{0}}+{\binom{n}{3}}+{\binom{n}{6}}+\cdots ={\frac{1}{3}}\left(2^{n}+2\cos {\frac{n\pi }{3}}\right)?$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs, divisor-counting-function

I think it is solved with double counting. I tried to write unfolded, but I failed to solve the exercise. Can you help me?

Comment: Hint: Let $\omega = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$, we have $1 + \omega^k + \omega^{2k} = \begin{cases}3, & k \equiv 0 \pmod 3\\0, &k \not\equiv 0\pmod 3\end{cases}$, now apply binomial theorem to $(1+1)^n + (1+\omega)^n + (1+\omega^2)^n$, what do you get?

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1385059/11619) or [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1539606/11619) or [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1563905/11619).

Comment: An interesting approach is to use induction.

Answer (score 1):

that is a [multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) of the binomial series