# Binomial coefficients with step

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I know how to find 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{{n}\choose{2k}} = 2^{k-1}.$$

But I have no idea how to find $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}{{n}\choose{3k}}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/4\rfloor}{{n}\choose{4k}}$. Some hint could be useful.

Comment: what is the summation index? summing from which range?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563905/roots-of-unity-filter-identity-involving-sum-k-ge-0-binomn3k), it describes with details case of $\binom{n}{3k}$, similar can be done for $\binom{n}{4k}$

Comment: k must be correctly bounded ... perhaps use 2k , 3k as indexes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z_1=e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $z_2=e^{-2i\pi/3}$, then
$$(1+1)^n + (1+z_1)^n + (1+z_2)^n=2^n +2\cos(n\pi/3)=3\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}{{n}\choose{3k}}$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}{{n}\choose{3k}}=\frac{2^n+2\cos(n\pi/3)}{3}=
\frac{2^n+a_n}{3}$$
where $a_n$ is the 6-periodic sequence $\{2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1\}$.

The details can be found here: [Roots of unity filter, identity involving $\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{3k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563905/roots-of-unity-filter-identity-involving-sum-k-ge-0-binomn3k)

By using a similar method, it turns out that for $n\geq 1$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/4\rfloor}{{n}\choose{4k}}=2^{n-2}+2^{(n-2)/2}\cos(n\pi/4).$$
See the nice answer of robjohn.

Comment: I know that there is a way to find the formula that uses only integer functions of integer argument...

Comment: A-ha, I understood that it can be just split into cases not to use cosine.

Comment: and that gives a nice information on the divisibility of the neighbours of $2^n$

Comment: I believe that the coefficient of $\cos(n\pi/4)$ should be $2^{(n-2)/2}$

Comment: @robjohn Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: As you state, this doesn't work for $n=0$. We need to add $\frac{(1-1)^n}4=\frac{[n=0]}4$ to the mix

Comment: @robjohn  I stated for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I stated that you stated ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$, then
$$
\frac{1+\omega^n+\omega^{-n}}3=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{if }n\equiv0\pmod3\\
0&\text{if }n\not\equiv0\pmod3\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}\binom{n}{3k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1+\omega^k+\omega^{-k}}3\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2^n}3+\frac{(1+\omega)^n}3+\frac{\left(1+\omega^{-1}\right)^n}3\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2^n}3+\frac{e^{\pi in/3}}3+\frac{e^{-\pi in/3}}3\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2^n+2\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}3\right)}3
\end{align}
$$
Note that $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}3\right)=\{2,1,-1,-2,-1,1\}$ when $n\equiv\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\pmod6$.

---

$$
\frac{1+i^n+(-1)^n+(-i)^n}4=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{if }n\equiv0\pmod4\\
0&\text{if }n\not\equiv0\pmod4\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/4\rfloor}\binom{n}{4k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1+i^k+(-1)^k+(-i)^k}4\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2^n}4+\frac{(1+i)^n}4+\frac{0^n}4+\frac{(1-i)^n}4\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2^n}4+\frac{2^{n/2}e^{\pi in/4}}4+\frac{0^n}4+\frac{2^{n/2}e^{-\pi in/4}}4\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2^n+[n=0]+2^{n/2}\cdot2\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}4\right)}4
\end{align}
$$
Note that $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}4\right)=\left\{2,\sqrt2,0,-\sqrt2,-2,-\sqrt2,0,\sqrt2\right\}$ when $n\equiv\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\pmod8$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> I believe that `@RobertZ` and `@robjohn` answers provide the straightforward and simpler methods. However, it will be useful to see another point of view which is somehow related to the above mentioned answers.

---

With $\ds{\ell = 1,2,3,\ldots}$ 
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor\,{n/\ell}\,\rfloor}{n \choose \ell k}} &\ =\
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\ \overbrace{
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{+}}\,\,{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{\ell k + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{n \choose \ell k}}\ =\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{+}}\,\,{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{1 \over z^{\ell}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{+}}\,\,{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
{1 \over 1 - 1/z^{\ell}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{+}}\,\,
{z^{\ell - 1}\,\,\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{\ell} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}

---

The integrand has $\ds{\ell}$ simple poles which are the roots $\ds{\braces{r}}$ of $\ds{z^{\ell} - 1 = 0}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor\,{n/\ell}\,\rfloor}{n \choose \ell k}} & =
\sum_{r}{r^{\ell - 1}\,\,\pars{1 + r}^{n} \over \ell r^{\ell - 1}} =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over \ell}\sum_{r}\pars{1 + r}^{n}}\,,\qquad
\ell = 1,2,3,\ldots
\end{align}

---

For instance,
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rclcl}
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over \color{#f00}{1}}\pars{1 + 1}^{n}} & \ds{=} &  \ds{2^{n}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor\,{n/\color{#f00}{2}}\,\right\rfloor}
{n \choose \color{#f00}{2}k}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over \color{#f00}{2}}\bracks{\pars{1 + 1}^{n} + \pars{1 - 1}^{n}}} & \ds{=} & 
\ds{2^{n - 1}\,\, +\,\, \half\,\delta_{n0}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor\,{n/\color{#f00}{3}}\,\right\rfloor}
{n \choose \color{#f00}{3}k}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over \color{#f00}{3}}\sum_{k = -1}^{1}\pars{1 + \exp\pars{2\pi k\ic \over 3}}^{n}} & \ds{=} & 
\ds{{1 \over 3}\bracks{2^{n} + 2\cos\pars{n\,{\pi \over 3}}}}
\\[5mm]
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor\,{n/\color{#f00}{4}}\,\right\rfloor}
{n \choose \color{#f00}{4}k}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over \color{#f00}{4}}\bracks{\pars{1 + 1}^{n} + \pars{1 - 1}^{n} + \pars{1 + \ic}^{n} + \pars{1 - \ic}^{n}}} &&
\\ & \ds{=} & 
\ds{{1 \over 4}\bracks{2^{n} + \delta_{n0} +
2^{n/2 + 1}\,\cos\pars{n\,{\pi \over 4}}}}&&
\end{array}\right.
$$