# The sum of combination $ \sum _{i \equiv q \pmod p} {n \choose i}$

Tags: combinations, binomial-theorem

Let $p$ be natural number such that $p \geq 2$. And $q$ is natural number such that $ 0 \leq q \leq p-1 $.
What is $ \sum _{i \equiv q \pmod p} {n \choose i}$? I solved it for $p=2, 3, 4, 5, 7$, but I cannot generalize it. I solved it by using complex number $w$ such that $w^p=1$ and Binomial theorem. Is there better ways?

Comment: I think the method using the binomial theorem is the best, and it also works for $p$ which are not prime.

Comment: then is there no generalizing?

Comment: @추민서 Do you mean generalizing past these $p$ using the binomial theorem, or generalizing past these $p$ using some other method?

Comment: I want to generalizing with real numbers.

Comment: Complex numbers is indeed the way to go, and it generalizes to all cases. The fancy name for this technique is Characters (in representation theory).

Comment: by using it, I can generalize it? When $p=7$, it is very complex to solve it. is there another solution using characters?

Comment: The formulas necessarily become more complicated as $p$ increases. Basically it is a combination of the binomial theorem and a discrete Fourier transform. When looking at representations of a cyclic group (see Calvin Lin's comment) we can replace characters with a DFT. Actually that applies to all finite abelian groups, but that's not relevant here.

Comment: I hate to blow my own trumpet, but the only example I can find quickly is [an old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1385084/11619). The same technique applies to [variants of the harmonic infinite series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2075681/11619) as long as the DFT-component causing divergence vanishes.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1563905/11619) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2136738/11619) have examples with $p=3$. You know about those already. I am adding them just to link more related questions.