# Combinatorially proving $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{4n}{4k} = 2^{4n-2} + (-1)^{n}2^{2n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to to combinatorially prove the following identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{4n}{4k} = 2^{4n-2} + (-1)^{n}2^{2n-1}$$

However, I don't have any idea how to start or what to count. I would appreciate any suggestions that helps me get the idea how to even start to prove these kind of identities.

Comment: Could you please show your progress or any efforts?

Comment: “how to start” is probably with a much simpler problem. But some things to look for: $\binom{a}{b}$ is the number of subsets of a given $a$-element set that have exactly $b$ element. $2^c$ is the number of subsets of a $c$-element set that have any number of elements. $(-1)^n$ as a factor adds or subtracts depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1385059/11619) is a different sum involving binomial coefficients with a period of four. The same technique (see my answer) can be used to prove this, but I'm not sure I would call it combinatorial :-)

Answer (score 2):

Expand => $$\frac {(1 + x)^{4n} \pm \left((1 + x)^{2n} + (1 - x)^{2n}\right)}{8}$$

We can substitute x = 1 after equating to the expansion of the above.

Hint:
$$\left[\binom{k}{0} + \binom{k}{1} + \dots + \binom{k}{k}\right] = 2^{k}$$

While solving, you will eventually end up at k = 2n, 4n.

Please note: I have added ± so that you can eventually realize whether to subtract or add the binomials when relating
$$\binom{4n}{r} \text{ & } \binom{2n}{r - 1}, \binom{2n}{r+1}$$

Hint: You can use Pascal's triangle to see the pattern or something like

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left[\binom{2n - 1}{2k} + \binom{2n - 1}{2k - 1}\right] = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k}$$

Comment: Tested OK: [python-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEUZP.png)
I just wanted to be sure about my own solution.

Comment: You can also use complex number $i$, As it will get all $4$rth powers for you.
$(1+i) \text { & } ( 1 - i)$